# I have graph.db folder from neo4j. It contains lot of neostore*.* files. How do i export a csv file from this?

Tags: csv, neo4j, graph-databases

I have graph.db folder from neo4j. It contains lot of neostore*.* files. How do i export a csv file from this ?

Note: I have this graph.db sent from my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Download and install Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/download/) if you haven't already
2. Move the `graph.db` directory that you have now into the `data/` directory of the fresh Neo4j installation, replacing the existing `graph.db` directory in the fresh Neo4j instance. (Note: If you are using the desktop Neo4j application you can simply choose the location of your existing graph.db directory when starting Neo4j).
   [image]
3. Start Neo4j server
4. To generate CSVs you have a few options:

   1. **Export from Neo4j Browser** With Neo4j running, open your web browser and navigate to `http://localhost:7474`. Execute a Cypher query. Click on the "Download" icon and choose "Export CSV" to download a CSV representation of the data returned. See screenshot below.[image]
   2. **neo4j-shell-tools** Use [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import) to export results of a Cypher query. Use `-o file.csv` to specify output should be written to CSV file.

See [this blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/) for more info.

Comment: Hi William Lyon, thank you for the information, this really helps. Is there any way where i can understand the neo4j data and i want to extract a csv file from that, which i will analyze a suitable data model and load that into hbase.   The whole point is I have neo4j data which i want to convert to hbase. Thanks, Rajesh.